# Integrating factor method to solve the differential equation $\frac{ 1 }{x} \frac{ dy}{dx }+ y = x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

The question is:

Use the integrating factor method to solve the differential equation

$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x^2$

for the case where $y=1 $ when $x=0$

What I have done so far:

$\frac{dy}{dx}+xy=x^3$

$ S(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+S(x)xy=S(x)x^3 $ --- Multiply ODE with integrating factor $S(x)$

and demand that it satisfies the  condition $\frac{dS}{dx}=S(x) {x}$

$\int \frac {1}{S} dS = \int xdx$

$lnS = \frac{x^2}{2}+c$

$S(x)= Ae^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ and setting A = 1

$S(x)= e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$

$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}y)=x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$

$e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}y = \int x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx $

I'm having trouble integrating the right hand side. I have tried to do it by parts but cannot cancel out terms. There may be an error in my calculation up to that point as well.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $u = x^2$, which reduces to another integral which you'd solve using Integration by Parts.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got the final answer.

Comment: Note that when integrating the integral on the right by parts you should let $u=x^2$ and $dv=xe^{x^2/2}dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I = \int x^3 e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$$

$u=x^2\implies \frac{du}{dx} = 2x$

$$I = \int x\cdot u\cdot \frac{1}{2x}\cdot e^{\frac{u}{2}} dx = \frac{1}{2}\int ue^{\frac{u}{2}}du$$

Then we do this by parts:

Let $v = \int e^{\frac{u}{2}}du\implies v = 2e^{\frac{u}{2}}$

Let $w = u\implies  \frac{dw}{du} = 1$

Then $$I = \frac{1}{2}\left(2ue^{\frac{u}{2}}-2\int e^{\frac{u}{2}}du \right) =ue^{\frac{u}{2}}-2e^{\frac{u}{2}} +C$$

$$I = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(x^2-2)+C$$